# Compact set of $C[0,1]$ is nowhere dense using Arzelá-Ascoli

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let a compactum $K$ in the set of real-valued continuous functions $C([0,1])$ with domain $[0,1]$, endowed with the supremum distance, be given. I want to prove that $K$ is nowhere dense, i.e. it has empty interior. By Arzelá-Ascoli theorem, it follows that $K$ is uniformly equicontinuous. I now want to deduce that for any $u\in K$ there exists a $v\in C([0,1]) \setminus K$, such that $\left\| u-v \right\|_{\infty}$ can be arbitrarily small, then the claim should follow. However, I don't know how to construct this $v$. Any help is appreciated!